# Powershell: delete duplicate entry in arraylist

Tags: powershell, arraylist, unique, powershell-2.0

In my Powershellscript I read some data from a csv-File in an Arraylist.

In the second step I eliminate every line without the specific char: `(`.

At the third step I want to eliminate every double entries.

Example for my list:

```
Klein, Jürgen (Klein01); salesmanagement national 
Klein, Jürgen (Klein01); salesmanagement national 
Meyer, Gerlinde (Meyer02); accounting 
Testuser 
Admin1
Müller, Kai (Muell04); support international
```

I use the following script:

```
$Arrayusername = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$NewArraylistuser = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Arrayusername = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\User\Userlist.csv"
for ($i=0; $i -le $Arrayusername.length; $i++)
{
    if ($Arrayusername[$i] -like "*(*")
    {
        $NewArraylistuser.Add($Arrayusername_ads[$i])
    }
    $Array_sorted = $NewArraylistuser | sort
    $Array_sorted | Get-Unique
}
```

But the variable `$Array_sorted` still has double entries.
I don´t find the mistake.

Comment: Your code needs one more `}` and that might affect the outcome. When I test with your data, Get-unique removes the duplicate name. Your code could be `$result = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\User\Userlist.csv" | Where-Object { $_ -like  '*(*' } | Sort-Object -Unique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Ideas how you could change your code:

1. Use the existing Command to import .csv files with the Delimiter `;`.
2. Filter the output with `Where-Object` to only include Names with `(`.
3. Select only unique objects with `Select-Object`, or if you want to sort the Object, use the `Sort-Object` with the same paramets.

Something like this should work:

```
Import-csv -Delimiter ';' -Header "Name","Position" -Path "C:\Temp\User\Userlist.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*(*"} | Sort-Object -Unique -Property Name,Position
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tested your code an it worked well. When I use the "-Encoding UTF8" parameter I get the following Errormessage "No Parameter found corresponding to the parameter "Encoding"

Comment: Hey @ThomasLang, I'm glad that I could help. The `-Encoding` Parameter only exists since Powershell v3. If you are still using v2, is will throw an error (like the one you mentioned). You may want to upgrade your Powershell Version in the near future ;). Also, if the answer solved your problem, you can mark the answer as correct (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)